# "Right" way to deal with adding packages to path

Tags: path, haskell

I downloaded and installed the Haskell Platform. And It got installed (default) to `/usr/local/haskell/`

I want to add the binarys inside `/usr/local/haskell/bin/` to my path. But I dont want (if possible) to change my path..

What would be the best course of action here? Should i move the `haskell/bin/*` to `local/bin` or is it the best practice to add the haskell folder to path as?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to change your `$PATH`?  The "right" way is _not_ to move the binaries somewhere else (they may overwrite other executables that happen to have the same names, and they may not work at all if they assume that binaries that they themselves are using are accessible by the original installation path).

Comment: @Kusalananda Dont want it to get "bloated". Perhaps this train of thought is wrong though. Im thinking it would be better to add the files to the "correct" folders instead of simply adding and adding to $PATH

Comment: @Kusalananda So you are saying that I should append to the $PATH variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative approach to updating `$PATH` that is fairly common is to create symlinks to the binaries somewhere that is already listed under `$PATH`, for example, in `/usr/local/bin`.

You can accomplish that with:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ sudo ln -s ../haskell/bin/* .
```

(But, before you do, make sure you inspect the list of binaries in `/usr/local/haskell/bin/` and check that creating the symbolic links makes sense. You might decide to only symlink a subset of the files as well.)

One reason why you would *not* want to move the binaries themselves is that many times binaries that are distributed in binary form in tarballs are written in a way that they can work when unpacked anywhere in the system. In order to do so, they often try to detect where they are installed (most often by looking at `/proc/self/exe`.) By doing so, they can find the parent directory `/usr/local/haskell` where they expect to find other libraries and files they need. Creating symlinks typically doesn't interfere with such mechanisms, since they'll still be able to find the actual binaries under `/usr/local/haskell/bin`, successfully locating installation path.

Another reason not to move the binaries is that later on if you want to uninstall Haskell you can simply delete the whole `/usr/local/haskell` directory, you don't need to *remember* that some of the binaries were moved to `/usr/local/bin` and, even if you do remember that, you don't need to recall which ones belong to Haskell (assuming you've used this method to install more than one software package.) You *do* end up with some broken symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` if you uninstall Haskell by just deleting the directory, but they're harmless and it's easy to point out which ones belong to Haskell, since they'll all have `../haskell/bin` in their name, so they're easy to clean up too.